# Making a Shield-based Weapon Master

Tags: character-creation, mutants-and-masterminds-3e

Is the math right on [this character sheet](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1hi7EZv5sSbHRt-VEuuPkpBGl8I6klECrCgOjKp5EPEg/edit?usp=sharing)?

Points of Interest:
1) Deflection's affects on active defense. 
2) Offense Stats

> **Riot Act: Alex Ryder**
>   **ABILITIES (50pp)**
>   Strength: 3     Agility: 5          Fighting: 7     Awareness: 1
>   Stamina: 2      Dexterity: 5            Intellect: 0        Presence: 2
>
> **POWERS (10pp)**
>
> - **Shield Block**: Deflect 7, Easily Removable
> - **Shield Bash**: Affliction 7 (Resisted by Fortitude; Impaired, Hindered, Incapacitated), Easily Removable
>
> **EQUIPMENT**
>   **Vehicle:** Motorcycle
>
> **ADVANTAGES (17pp)**
>   Defensive Roll 4, Equipment 5, Evasion, Improved Critical (Shield), All Out Attack, Move-by Action, Interpose, Instant Up, Power Attack and Improved Trip
>
> **SKILLS (45pp)**
>   Acrobatics 8 (+13), Athletics 8 (+11), Close Combat: Shield 6 (+13), 
>   Deception 8 (+10), Expertise: History 6 (+6), Expertise: Weapons 8 (+8), 
>   Intimidation 6 (+8), Investigation 6 (+6), Perception 8 (+9), 
>   Ranged Combat: Weapon (+13), Sleight of Hand 6 (+11), Stealth 8 (+13), 
>   Vehicles 4 (+9)
>
> **OFFENSE**
>   Initiative +5
>   Throw +13, Ranged Damage 3
>   Shield +13, Close Damage 3
>
> **DEFENSE (28pp)**
>   Dodge: 12       Fortitude: 8
>   Parry:  14      Toughness: 6/2*
>   Will: 9
>
> **Origin: Training.**
>
> **Motivation-Patriotism.**
>
> **Complications:**
>   Secret- Is actually the descendant of the WW2 villain known as Vanguard, as opposed Riot Act’s claims of  being a descendant of WW2 hero the Patriot. 
>   Vigilante- Acts with little disregard to the law.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The linked character is a perfectly legal PL 10 character. Weak, but valid. As for your concerns:

1) Deflect has **no** effect on defenses. If the character takes the Defend action then he may use his Deflect ranks in place of his active defenses. That's usually going to be a bad choice in this case, since Deflect is only rank 7 and the defenses are 12 or 14, but being able to Deflect attacks at range is good for protecting other people.

> **Defend (Standard Action):** Rather than attacking, you focus on defense. Make an opposed check of your appropriate active defense versusany attack made on you until the start of your next turn. Add 10 to any roll of 10 or less that you make on these checks, just as if you spent a hero point (thus ensuring a minimum roll of 11). The attacker must equal or exceed your opposed check result in order to hit you.

2) The offenses listed are mostly valid. +13 attack for Strength damage 3 or Affliction 7 (presumably with a concussion trapping). 
 The Ranged Attack skill should have "weapon" changed to "thrown" or "shield", but is otherwise fine.

Note that the Affliction doesn't have the Ranged extra so it cannot be used with a thrown shield. Also that the character has no way to return the shield to himself, meaning he has to walk over and pick it up after each throw.